# Do I need to consider the header size to calculate the original datagram?

Tags: computer-networks

The following question is related to finding the size of the original datagram. The formula for original datagram size is: Data length of first packet + (Total length of subsequent packets * no. of subsequent packets. Do I also need to consider the header size for the first packet sent?

And what if the MF for the first packet was 1? What would have been the offset of the second last packet in that case?

**Here's the full question:**

You receive a packet whose data length is 900 bytes, ID is 2398 and the MF flag is set to 0.
You received the remaining 12 packets, each of whose total length is 1945 bytes, ID is 2398
and the MF flag is set to 1. All of these packets’ header size is 25 bytes.

I. Find the packet size of the original datagram

II. Find the value of the offset field of the 2nd last packet [First data byte number starts at
0]